# react-router causing errors - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Why do I get these errors when putting into use react-router

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpxgI.png)

[bootstrap nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kG9S.png)

[index.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P97Mt.png)

[app.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTs8z.png)

[debug photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHgfV.png)

I tried many things nothing worked for me.

Comment: Provide the code from `components.tsx` line 66 and also provide context since that is where the error is occurring. You might need to provide the entire component code. The current code block does not show the `useState` portion.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I edited the post. At all there is no components.tsx file. I just started the project. I created react app, then installed react-router and that is all. I didn't use any hooks yet. On the screenshots, I provided you will see "Home", "Page1", and "Page2". These pages only consist of plain div element, no hooks.

Comment: that might be your issue. the errors talk about using hooks, so if you don't think you have used them, then you might want to check the template react app that was created for you.

Comment: I debug a bit and will apply a screenshot to the main post of where the errors coming in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue with version 6.11.2. I switched to 6.11.1 and it works fine.

Comment: Hey, I'm using react-router-dom version 6.11.1